# PayPal gateway has rejected request. The transaction was refused as a result of a duplicate invoice ID supplied

Tags: paypal

```
Magento 1.9.1
Porto theme
```

Never had a problem with Paypal. Now I received an Email from the default Email address on the account with the Subject line:

```
Subject: Payment Transaction Failed Reminder
```

The body of the Email is as follows:

```
Payment transaction failed.
Reason
PayPal gateway has rejected request. The transaction was refused as a result of a duplicate invoice ID supplied. Attempt with a new invoice ID (#10536: Invalid Data).
Checkout Type
onepage
Customer:
(customer name here) <customer Email here>
Items
(products here)
Total:
USD 74.12
Billing Address:
(customer billing address here)
United States
T: (customer phone number)
Shipping Address:
(shipping address here)
United States
T: (phone number here)
Shipping Method:
Local Delivery
Payment Method:
Debit or Credit Card
Date & Time:
Aug 24, 2017 7:55:12 AM
```

**Why did this happen and what do I need to do to prevent it from happening in the future?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue usually occurs when PayPal attempts to create a new invoice (usually incremental) but the system notes that there is the same the invoice number already exists. In your case, look into magento invoices and you should find invoice #10536. This issue often times occurs due to roll back in the database, say during the backup restore. Or if you have database duplicate.

As a quick workaround without digging into the issue, you can follow these steps in PayPal profile.

My Account >Profile >My Selling Tools >Credit Card Statement Name >"Allow multiple payments per invoice ID"

Comment: Thank you for your information, my question last 2 years working good why suddenly happen this issue? what is the main cause for this issue? @Icon